# How to show and hide block of code in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my AngularJS project I have a task: when both point directives with md-autocomplete from code under are filled results directive must be shown immediately without any button. And when I press cross (like in picture to clear the autocomplete field) the block will hide also without any button

My code is working not so correct

And note  for an error in browser console please.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.interim = false;

    $scope.go = function(){
        $scope.interim = true;
    };
});

app.directive('point', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div layout layout-sm="column">' +
                    '<md-autocomplete ng-disabled="isDisabled" md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)" md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0" placeholder="{{place}}">' +
                        '<md-item-template>' +
                             '<span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>' +
                        '</md-item-template>' +
                    '</md-autocomplete>' +
                '</div>',
        controller: PointCtrl,
        scope: {
            place: '@',
            go: '&'
        }
    }
});

function PointCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $q, $log) {

    $scope.simulateQuery = false;
    $scope.isDisabled = false;

    $scope.cities = loadAll();
    $scope.querySearch = querySearch;
    $scope.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;


    function loadAll() {
        var allCities = 'London, Manchester, Liverpool, Paris, Lion, Prague, New York, Dallas';

        return allCities.split(/, +/g).map(function (city) {
            return {
                value: city.toLowerCase(),
                display: city
            };
        });
    }

    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? $scope.cities.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : $scope.cities,
            deferred;
        if ($scope.simulateQuery) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
            return deferred.promise;
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }

    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

        return function filterFn(city) {
            return (city.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
        $log.log('value: ' + item.display);
        $scope.chosenPoint = item.display;

        $scope.$watch('chosenPoint', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== '') {             //if autocomplete field is completed
                $scope.go();             //how block with results directive
            } else {
                //$scope.hideBlock();              //if not or cleared - hide block
            }
        });
    }
}

app.directive('results', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: red; font-size: 30px; text-align: center" ng-show="interim">I need to show this block when autocomplete fields are filled and hide it when both or, at least, one of the fields are cleared, pressing a cross</div>'
    }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.css">
    <style>
        .resultsBlock {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        h3 {  margin: 20px 0;  }

        md-autocomplete button{
            position: relative;
            left: 100px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        md-autocomplete input:not(.md-input) {
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 40%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="resultsBlock" layout="column">
            <point place="point_1"></point>
            <h3>Block of text will be shown when both autocomplete fields will be completed</h3>
            <results></results>
            <point place="point_2" go="go()"></point>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `point` directive, when you click on `x` to delete the selection, the `selectionItemChange` function is invoked with the `item` parameter undefined. That is why you were getting an error in your console.

Change your function to detect that condition.

**Your `point` directive**

```
function selectedItemChange(item) {

    //add event emitter
    $scope.$emit("pointChange", item);

    if (item) {
        $scope.chosenPoint = item.display;
    } else {
        //set to empty string if 'item' parameter is undefined
        $scope.chosenPoint = '';
    }

    if ( $scope.chosenPoint !== '') { 
        //if autocomplete field is completed
        $scope.go();
    }
}
```

Also notice the addition of and event emitter. Listen for that event in your main controller and use it to clear the block.

**Your main controller**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.interim = false;

    $scope.$on("pointChange", function (e,item) {
        if (!item) {
          console.log("Clearing block");
          $scope.interim = false;
        }
    });

    $scope.go = function(){
        $scope.interim = true;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank's. But there are some moments that don't work: 
1) I need to show block when both fields are completed. But for now it's enough to select second one for showing the block;
2)When clear the block and select another one the block doesn't show again (if clear first field);

Comment: I don't want to do your homework for you. This example shows two ways to communicate from directive to controller: invoking a directive specific function or emitting a custom event. Your controller can use one or the other or both. How would **you** do it?